# If we square a function, what happens to its Fourier transform?

Tags: fourier-analysis

Suppose we have a function $f$ and its Fourier transform:
$$F[f](t) = \displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\cdot e^{-itx}dx$$
Now we are interested in:
$$F[f^2](t) = \displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty f^2(x)\cdot e^{-itx}dx$$
Can we express $F[f^2](t)$ in terms of $F[f](t)$? Or if that isn't possible, can we approximate $F[f^2](t)$ using $F[f](t)$?

The only property of the Fourier-transform I could find that might be helpful is Parseval's equation:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)^2 dx = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty [Ff(t)]^2 dx$$

I was hoping to use this to write something like:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty F[f^2](t)  \stackrel{?}{=}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)^2 dx = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty (F[f](t))^2 dx$$
Then maybe use this in an approximation.

Comment: HINT:  Use the Convolution Theorem.

Comment: Could it really be as simple as: $F[f^2](t) = ( F[f](t) )^2$? Just the component-wise squaring?

Comment: No, that isn't correct.  I've posted the form for the Fourier Transform of $f^2$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the [convolution theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem), we can write

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f^2(x)e^{-itx}\,dx=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty F(t')F(t-t')dt'$$

The Theorem is actually more general than this.  If $f$ and $g$ have Fourier Transforms $F$ and $G$, respectively, then the Fourier Transform of the product $fg$ is given by

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)g(x)e^{-itx}\,dx=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty F(t')G(t-t')dt'$$

Comment: What about if $f(x) =e^{-\alpha |x|^2}$? How to calculate explicity $\mathcal{F}(f^2)(\xi)$?

Comment: @Thiago The square of $f$ is $e^{-2\alpha |x^2|}$

Comment: My bad. I meant: If $f(x) = e^{-\alpha |x|^2.|x|^2}$, is there any rule to calculate $\hat{f}$ ?

Comment: Not in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: Even in terms on non elementary functions, do you indicate a good reference with this things?

Comment: @Thiago This is not relevant to the question asked here.  If you include the generalized hypergeometric function, then yes.